# Someone seems to be running ads for our business with incorrect or misleading information

Tags: google-ads

We've been getting a lot of people contacting us saying they saw an ad for our business advertising free services or services we do not provide as well as people coming from regions we do not operate in, we checked all of our socials and no such ads seem to be running. Most of this unwanted traffic comes from https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/ so we believe someone is running some kind of malicious ad campaign. Is there any way to investigate whether this is happening and somehow stop it?

Comment: Can you ask the people contacting you if they can send screenshots/links to the ad?

Comment: we have but most of them don't respond or describe the ad but say they have no screenshots or links